# How to retrieve multiple select value?

Tags: java, jsp, select, portlet

Does anyone know how to retrieve multiple select value in jsp liferay portlet..

I have the following select box

```html
<form name="<portlet:namespace/>fm1" 
    method="post"
    action="
      <portlet:actionURL>
        <portlet:param name='nextPage' value='pm_addActivityResult.jsp'/>
      </portlet:actionURL>"
    onsubmit="return selectAllOptions('item_id')"> 

<table>
 <tr>
  <td> 

     <select multiple="multiple" id="item_id" name="item_id" size="1">
        <c:forEach items="${pageScope.itemList}" var="num">
            <option value="${num.id}">${num.type} ${num.model} ${num.serialNo}</option>
        </c:forEach>    
     </select>

  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<input type="submit" value="ADD" name="add"/>

</form>
```

I've tried the code below, but doesn't seem to work :(

```java
   String[] itemId = renderRequest.getParameterValues("item_id");
```

If anyone know, please let me know. I've been stuck doing this..

appreciate any help..thanks

Comment: did you place the select tag into a form tag and then submit the form?@Faiza Zain

Comment: yup, i place it into a form..and method is also post..

Comment: can you post html code snippet here after ForEach complete? take it from HTML source.

Comment: please post your action handler

Answer (score 1):

First since you are using form, I believe the form is pointing to an actionURL and not renderURL. Next if that is the case you are supposed to use actionRequest.getParameterValues("item_id"); instead of renderRequest assuming that you are overriding processAction.

Comment: yes, the form is pointing to an actionURL and not renderURL..          i try use actionRequest.getParameterValues("item_id"); but comes out an error java.lang.nullpointerexception....

Comment: That means form is not posted. Complete jsp and java file is required to know what is wrong and also your liferay-plugin-package.properties

Answer (score 1):

Try to print actionRequest.getParameterNames(), or iterate on it and print values.

Comment: can't use actionRequest.getParameterNames(), error : method getParameterNames in interface javax.portlet.PortletRequest cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Comment: don't use param in this method -  java.util.Enumeration<java.lang.String>  getParameterNames()
          Returns an Enumeration of String objects containing the names of the parameters contained in this request.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it!

It's quite complicated. I have a java file to passes data from one jsp form to another.

So, rather than using this code:

```
public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws PortletException,   IOException {

    Map<String,String[]> paramMap = request.getParameterMap();
    Set<String> params =  paramMap.keySet();

    for(String param:params){ 
        response.setRenderParameter(param, paramMap.get(param)[0]);

    }      
 }
```

I've used this one

```
 public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response) throws PortletException, IOException {

    Map<String,String[]> paramMap = request.getParameterMap();
    Set<String> params =  paramMap.keySet();

    for(String param:params){

        //string array check
        String[] paramValues = paramMap.get(param);
        response.setRenderParameter(param, paramValues);

    }     
}
```

That's how I solved it.